# Create unit test for Windows Form. .Net C#

Tags: .net, winforms, unit-testing, c#-4.0

There is form in which there are controls(textboxes,buttons).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public MWLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;


          }

    //there is text box!

        private void txtbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            if(!String.IsNullorEmpty(txtbox.Text))
            {
                btnOK.Enabled = true;   //for example
            }
        }
}
```

And in unit test should be getting Text from the txtBox 
for example: (not correct)

```
[TestMethod()]
            public void Form1Test()
            {
            try
            {

                MWLogin target = new MWLogin();
                if(MWLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                      string a = MWLogin.txtBox.Text; //this is no correct
                }

                Assert.IsTrue(true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Assert.Fail();
            }
        }
```

Please help! How get text from `txtBox` in form ( without static or public property in Form)

Comment: Try `target.txtBox.Text`. But something's not right. Your class is `Form1` but constructor is for `MWLogin` .

Comment: a typo) 
just an example.
yes there should be Form1 target = new Form1();

Answer (score 0):

You can not access to private member (txtbox is private). Try add public property:

```
public String TextBoxText { get { return txtbox.Text; } }
```

Now in unit test you can use:

```
string a = target .TextBoxText;
```